# PouchDB Grouping and Summarizing

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, nosql, pouchdb

I am using **pouchdb** and have a document structure like this:

```
{
 "_id": "1",
 "title": "Title",
 "categories": {
   "category1": {
     "salesx": [
       {
         "date": "2016-09-15 00:00:00",
         "qty": "2"
       },
       {
         "date": "2016-09-16 00:00:00",
         "qty": "3"
       }
     ],
     "salesy": [
       [
         {
           "date": "2016-09-15 00:00:00",
           "qty": "1"
         }
       ]
     ]
   }
 },
 "_rev": "rev"
}
```

I now want to get something like this as a result from pouchdb:

```
{
"_id": "1",
"title": "Title",
"categories": {
  "category1": {
    "salesx": 2 + 3 = 5,
    "salesy": [
      [
        {
          "date": "2016-09-15 00:00:00",
          "qty": "1"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
},
"_rev": "rev"
}
```

So, **salesx** should be grouped and the qty should be summarized.
**salesy** should not be changed.
I also want to add a *where clause* to the date field.

I tried to start with a map function which selects the correct dates. But I don't know what to emit to group the qty later.

```
function myMapFunction(doc) {
   doc.categories.forEach(category => {
       category.salesx.forEach(salex => {
           if (salex.date >= mydate) {
               emit(?)
           }
       })
   })
}
```

I can't find a good example on [pouchdb docs](https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html). They only provide examples for grouping multiple documents together.

Does anyone know how I can achieve grouping the document?

Comment: How do documents differ from one document to the other? I mean, which fields are changing? Can you provide an example of another document in addition to the one you provided already? It is needed in order to reproduce your situation.

Comment: Hi @user3405291 All documents look exactly like the one I already showed. Exept the number of entries in salex and the number of categories (e.g. category1, category2 ...) is modified.

Comment: For query based on `date` field, you are comparing with `mydate` in the view map function. Is `mydate` a constant value or is it a variable which can be different in each query?

Comment: `mydate` is different in each query. The general goal is to display the sales from x to y to the user.

Comment: If `mydate` varies with each query, it is not the best idea to include it in view map function to do comparisons. Instead maybe it is a better idea to generate a view map function which emits the `date` field values, and then do a query of the index generated by that view map function. Maybe [this documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/intro.html#find-many "Efficient Lookups - Find Many") would be helpful.

Comment: So I should iterate over categories and salesx and call `emit(date)` for each sale? And how can I then group my sales?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the documents like below, to convert the `qty` field from *string* values to *number* values, to be able to do math operations:

```
{
  "_id": "sale0000",
  "_rev": "2-5cd6fff48f9fd099481d3b523ff1191f",
  "title": "Title",
  "categories": {
    "category1": {
      "salesx": [
        {
          "date": "2016-09-15 00:00:00",
          "qty": 2
        },
        {
          "date": "2016-09-16 00:00:00",
          "qty": 3
        }
      ],
      "salesy": [
        [
          {
            "date": "2012-09-15 00:00:00",
            "qty": 1
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you mentioned in the comments:

> All documents look exactly like the one I already showed. Except the
>   number of entries in `salesx` and the number of categories (e.g.
>   `category1`, `category2` ...) is modified

Based on your above statement, I created in my sample database some documents with varying number of entries in `salesx` and varying number of `categoiry1`, `category2`, etc., but each `salesy` has only one entry.

Here is another one of my sample documents:

```
{
  "_id": "sale0002",
  "_rev": "3-12bf5c872fc124c1f0a5a4a108cb4f7a",
  "title": "Title",
  "categories": {
    "category1": {
      "salesx": [
        {
          "date": "2016-09-15 00:00:00",
          "qty": 2
        },
        {
          "date": "2016-09-16 00:00:00",
          "qty": 3
        },
        {
          "date": "2017-10-16 00:00:00",
          "qty": 9
        }
      ],
      "salesy": [
        [
          {
            "date": "2014-09-15 00:00:00",
            "qty": 1
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "category2": {
      "salesx": [
        {
          "date": "2018-01-15 00:00:00",
          "qty": 2
        },
        {
          "date": "2012-08-16 00:00:00",
          "qty": 3
        },
        {
          "date": "2015-10-16 00:00:00",
          "qty": 7
        }
      ],
      "salesy": [
        [
          {
            "date": "2011-03-15 00:00:00",
            "qty": 1
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I understand what exactly you intend, but I developed the following view map function:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.categories){
    for(var categ in doc.categories){
      var salesx_qty_sum=0;
      for(var i=0, len=doc.categories[categ].salesx.length; i<len; i++){
        salesx_qty_sum += doc.categories[categ].salesx[i].qty
      }
      emit(
        doc.categories[categ].salesy[0][0]['date'], //emit the date of salesy as the key
                                                    //my understanding is that you need to index/sort
                                                    //according to date of salesy
        [
          salesx_qty_sum, //emit the sum of qty for salesx as value
          doc.categories[categ].salesy[0][0]['qty'] //emit qty for salesy (unchanged) as value
        ]
      );
    }
  }
}
```

In my `sample` database I created four documents like yours with different number of entries in `salesx` and also varying number of categories. There is only one entry inside each `salesy`:

```
    $ curl -k -X GET 'https://admin:****@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/_all_docs'
{"total_rows":53,"offset":0,"rows":[
...
...
{"id":"_design/by_date","key":"_design/by_date","value":{"rev":"20-04cb881624aa819dac13f69c688f2124"}},
...
...
{"id":"sale0000","key":"sale0000","value":{"rev":"2-5cd6fff48f9fd099481d3b523ff1191f"}},
{"id":"sale0001","key":"sale0001","value":{"rev":"2-e8ee019fb0ad076b82d3f4772f736559"}},
{"id":"sale0002","key":"sale0002","value":{"rev":"3-12bf5c872fc124c1f0a5a4a108cb4f7a"}},
{"id":"sale0003","key":"sale0003","value":{"rev":"2-6d40368ddd16b9d02b908ea95d061c7e"}}
]}
```

The above view map (named `by_date`) is indexing my documents like below, in which the `key` is the date of `salesy`. Based your description, I assume there should be only one entry in each `salesy` in each category. Also, the `value` below is an array in which first element is sum of `qty` for `salesx`, and the second element is unchanged `qty` of `salesy`:

```
$ curl -k -X GET 'https://admin:admin@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/_design/by_date/_view/by_date'
{"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"sale0002","key":"2011-03-15 00:00:00","value":[12,1]},
{"id":"sale0000","key":"2012-09-15 00:00:00","value":[5,1]},
{"id":"sale0001","key":"2013-05-20 00:00:00","value":[12,1]},
{"id":"sale0002","key":"2014-09-15 00:00:00","value":[14,1]},
{"id":"sale0003","key":"2015-04-15 00:00:00","value":[5,1]},
{"id":"sale0003","key":"2018-04-05 00:00:00","value":[5,1]}
]}
```

You can query the `by_date` view with `startkey` and `endkey` to get the results between two dates, like this:

```
$ curl -k -X GET 'https://admin:admin@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/_design/by_date/_view/by_date?startkey="2013"&endkey="2015"'
{"total_rows":6,"offset":2,"rows":[
{"id":"sale0001","key":"2013-05-20 00:00:00","value":[12,1]},
{"id":"sale0002","key":"2014-09-15 00:00:00","value":[14,1]}
]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your huge answer. But I think you understand my purpose wrong. My document stores sales. I now want to summarize for example all sales from 01/01/2015 to 01/01/2016 and get them as a result from the database. So the result should contain the *title*, etc. and the number of sales from date x to date y.